# Filter not working on a join between three tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm having difficulty joining data from three tables.

This is an anonymous shopping cart for a real estate company. The inmuebles table holds the details of the properties.
If some wants to have a viewing I create a record in the temppropertylist table using their asp.net sessionid, and in the 
anonymouscart table I add a record of the property they are interested in.

I'm showing this in a gridview control so when I rebind it I need a query that pulls the information from the three tables,
showing all the property data, and whether or not each property has been selected for viewing. To do that it's sufficient
to have either the propertyid or a null from the anonymouscart to be joined to each record in the inmuebles table as I can use it to toggle a checkbox.

What I found was my original query was pulling information from the anonymous cart for all of the related records in the
temppropertylist table so I'm trying to filter that using the sessionid in the join but it now only shows inmuebles records where there 
is a related record in anonymouscart.

I've read every listing I could on Stackoverflow but I can't get my head around what I'm doing wrong

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[anonymouscart](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[temppropertylist_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[propertyid] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Id  temppropertylist_id timestamp                     propertyid
40  38                  2013-09-24 08:24:00.0772687 2
39  37                  2013-09-24 08:03:56.1163987 1

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temppropertylist](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[sessionID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[userID] [int] NULL,
[timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

ID  sessionID                   userID  timestamp
37  jgyo5i4vne35bcolow23je1q    NULL      2013-09-24 08:02:29.1129679
38  uuoawmav4jhi3hy3g3v4vr3o    NULL      2013-09-24 08:23:58.8604375

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inmuebles](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](99) NULL,
[tipodemanda] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[Descripcioni] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[PrecioVenta] [int] NULL,
[Imagen] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[onhold] [bit] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My query:

```
SELECT  inmuebles.title
    ,   inmuebles.Descripcioni
    ,   inmuebles.ID
    ,   inmuebles.PrecioVenta
    ,   inmuebles.imagen
    ,   MIN(anonymouscart.propertyID) AS propertyID
FROM inmuebles
FULL OUTER JOIN anonymouscart ON Inmuebles.ID = anonymouscart.propertyID
FULL OUTER JOIN temppropertylist ON anonymouscart.temppropertylist_id = temppropertylist.ID 
    AND (temppropertylist.sessionid = 'uuoawmav4jhi3hy3g3v4vr3o')
WHERE tipodemanda = 'venta'
    AND onhold = 0
GROUP BY
        inmuebles.title
    ,   inmuebles.Descripcioni
    ,   inmuebles.ID
    ,   inmuebles.PrecioVenta
    ,   inmuebles.imagen
```

This returns:

```
title        Descripcioni     id PrecioVenta imagen propertyid
'Two for One' 'This is a ....' 2  110000     NULL   2
```

But what I want is all the records from the inmuebles table with nulls for propertyid

This the data from the inmuebles table:

```
title           Descripcioni         id    PrecioVenta   imagen                     onhold  tipodemanda
'Casa Bodega',  'This is a...',     1,   11000,        '1_27152256.jpg',0,              'venta'
'Two for One',  'This is a...',   2,     110000,          NULL,             0,         'venta'
```

Comment: You should Left Outer join your Immeuble table to anonymouscart table

Comment: I tried that @Nadeem‗MK but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you show a data that contains the inmuebles table, please?

Comment: There are only two records in inmuebles at the moment. I'll add them above.

Comment: I've got two rows when the query above was executed, not one

Comment: Yes but one of the pageid fields should be null. You'll be seeing 1  and 2 because records are appearing for both sessionid's in the temppropertylist table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is necessary to use a derived table and only after that join the Inmuebles  table

```
SELECT  inmuebles.title
    ,   inmuebles.Descripcioni
    ,   inmuebles.ID
    ,   inmuebles.PrecioVenta
    ,   inmuebles.imagen
    ,   MIN(x.propertyID) AS propertyID 
FROM inmuebles
LEFT JOIN (SELECT anonymouscart.propertyID
           FROM anonymouscart JOIN temppropertylist
             ON anonymouscart.temppropertylist_id = temppropertylist.ID
           AND temppropertylist.sessionid = 'uuoawmav4jhi3hy3g3v4vr3o'
           ) x ON Inmuebles.ID = x.propertyID
WHERE tipodemanda = 'venta' AND onhold = 0
GROUP BY
        inmuebles.title
    ,   inmuebles.Descripcioni
    ,   inmuebles.ID
    ,   inmuebles.PrecioVenta
    ,   inmuebles.imagen
```